# How to add a content type field to newform.aspx

Tags: content-type, custom-form

I have a content type in a custom list form. When I click on new item I don't see the content type field on the newform.aspx form. I can see it on the edit for though.
Is there a way to have a content type field shown on a newform?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default using OOTB capabilities of SharePoint you can select the Content Type from **ITEMS** tab in ribbon like below image:

[image]

To add the Content Type field in new form of list you need to develop custom form.

You check my answer given here for possible approach to do something like you want:

[Add Content Type field to New Form](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/268952/add-content-type-field-to-new-form/268959#268959)

Or you can follow the steps given in the accepted answer from MSDN forum:

[Show the Content Type on NewForm.aspx](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/3d6062ee-e3f0-42cd-8872-3de2ee290b29/show-the-content-type-on-newformaspx).

Comment: Thanks Ganesh. One question though if i only add  a html code via jquery to my existing out of the box form to mimic the content type field and use presave action to submit the form will i need only the value of the new html in the presave action code?

Comment: If you are redirecting to the new form URL with the Content Type ID in it (as mentioned in first link) then you don't need to do anything. It will save data automatically

Comment: All good. I solved my issue by appending some html radio button(with images) to the form. When clicked i did some redirection based on the content type and it all seems to work just using the OOTB forms

Comment: Great. Glad it worked for you. Please upvote and accept it as an answer.